# Script to drop and recreate primary key with partition sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

what is the script to drop and recreated primary key constraint with partition function.

Comment: have you read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

Comment: If this is about Sql Server, why is it tagged with MySQL?

Comment: removed mysql tag